# GTK3, SVG, and Cairo widget gets a gtk-missing-image icon overlay

Tags: python-3.x, svg, gtk3, cairo, glade

I have a custom widget that I am porting from Python 2 with GTK2 to Python3 with GTK3. I can get it working just fine using a toy example as shown below:

[image: working]

The button is there to change the widget from green to orange to red. Don't ask more.

However, as soon as I include it in a glade file, get this garbage:

[image: Broken]

Which has the `gtk-missing-image` icon superimposed on my widget.

The code is a mess with much inheritance and "clever" things hence why there is no code quoted. Either a hint as to why that could be or better yet, a good example of a SVG widget with the ability to change the colours would be welcome.

There's more!

Here is a toy code. It works fine in my toy program (widget SVG appears) but when I load it via glade, I get a `gtk-missing-image` instead.

```
 class Lamp(gtk.Image):
    """A new lamp?"""

    __gtype_name__ = "Lamp"
    off_colour = gobject.property(type=str, default="grey40")
    on_colour = gobject.property(type=str, default="#00ff00")
    fault_colour = gobject.property(type=str, default="#ff0000")

    def __init__(self):
        super(Lamp, self).__init__()
        self._logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
        self._logger.info("Initialised NEW Lamp.")
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        self.path = os.path.join(dir_path, "Lamp.svg")
        self.width = 128
        self.height = 128
        self.preserve_aspect_ratio = True
        self.pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(
            self.path,
            self.width,
            self.height,
            self.preserve_aspect_ratio)
        self.set_from_pixbuf(self.pixbuf)
        self.connect("draw", self.on_draw)

    def on_draw(self, widget, event):
        """When the "draw" event fires, this is run."""
        self._logger.debug("%s called.", inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)
        # … What does here?
```

Comment: Can you include your glade file?

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev No I cannot. It is not open source. My apologies. However, you pointed me in the right direction!!! `<property name="stock">gtk-missing-image</property>` was included for all Lamp widgets. That's wrong. WOOT. Thank you so much kind stranger.

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev Could you write a short answer? I'll give you some fake internet points. :+1:

Comment: It's absolutely [ok](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to answer your own question

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev I know. However, I want to pass you some fake internet points to say thank you.